# Jax-b is interpreting too much while unmarshalling

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling, jaxb2

I have a boolean field called `a` and two methods `void setA(String a)` and `boolean isA()`. I have set `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)` and used `@XmlAttribute` for the setter.

Because the getter returns a boolean value but the setter expects a string JAX-B just ignores this setter. This is the cause for all kinds of bugs in the code because boolean values are not set correctly and debugging that is very annoying.

Is there a way to tell JAX-B to use the setter? Why is JAX-B confused by the getter method at all, I though using `XmlAccessType.NONE` prevents all that implicit interpreting?

Plan B would be to let JAX-B fails if such a constellation appears, but how can this be done?

Thankful for any hint :-)

Comment: The method `setA(String a)` is not a setter for field `a` according to the JavaBeans spec, since its argument is of the wrong type. And JAXB relies on the JavaBeans conventions. If you can, add a method `setA(boolean a)`. You could simply call this from the String-based method after conversion (or whatever logic is in there). Maybe someone will come up with a more appropriate solution (*cough* Blaise Doughan *cough*).

Comment: Yeah that is bugging me aswell that the code doesn't keep to the conventions, but these constructs for extracting boolean values are used very often, and if I just click through the code and fix them I am sure to miss some. Can JAX-B not just fail, when the convention is hurt?

Comment: Ah, it's in more than one place. Well, I don't have some answer ready for that. Let's see if someone pops up with a good suggestion, assuming this is possible. Some sort of type adapter could do it, maybe.

Comment: @G_H - I have added an answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7876493/jax-b-is-interpreting-to-much-while-unmarshalling/7877499#7877499, but Kevin had pretty much covered the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using `@XmlAccessType.FIELD` as suggested by [Kevin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7876493/jax-b-is-interpreting-to-much-while-unmarshalling/7877036#7877036) combined with an `XmlAdapter` to get the behaviour you are looking for:

**Root**

To get this example to work with the JAXB-RI I need to make the field of type `Boolean`.  If you are using [EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) then you can make the field `boolean`.

```
package forum7876493;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

@XmlRootElement
public class Root {

    @XmlAttribute
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(BooleanAdapter.class)
    private Boolean a;

    public boolean isA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(String s) {
        this.a = "yes".equals(s) || "on".equals(s) || "in".equals(s);
    }

}
```

**BooleanAdapter**

The `XmlAdapter` is where you can add the logic that you have in your `setA(String)` method.

```
package forum7876493;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class BooleanAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Boolean> {

    @Override
    public Boolean unmarshal(String s) throws Exception {
        return "yes".equals(s) || "on".equals(s) || "in".equals(s);
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(Boolean b) throws Exception {
        if(b) {
            return "yes";
        }
        return "no";
    }

}
```

**Demo**

```
package forum7876493;

import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        Root root = (Root) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("src/forum7876493/input.xml"));

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);
    }

}
```

**input.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root a="on"/>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root a="yes"/>
```

**UPDATE**

Alternatively you could introduce a `String` getter for the `a` property.  You would need to make the `isA()` method as `@XmlTransient`:

```
package forum7876493;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;

@XmlRootElement
public class Root {

    private boolean a;

    @XmlTransient
    public boolean isA() {
        return a;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getA() {
        if(a) {
            return "yes";
        }
        return "no";
    }

    public void setA(String s) {
        this.a = "yes".equals(s) || "on".equals(s) || "in".equals(s);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks that works, but having to use Boolean instead of boolean is annoying. This adds one possible null-pointer hazzard. Is there any way to use primitives?

Comment: @FranzKafka - I have added an update where by adding a `getA()` method you can have the field be of type `boolean`.  Alternatively if you use EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) as your JAXB provider you can use the first approach with a `boolean` field:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/search/label/jaxb.properties

Answer (score 3):

Given that you're already using XmlAccessorType annotation, I guess you already know that you can use `@XmlAccessType.FIELD` and have JAXB look at the class fields rather than setter methods when deciding what to marshal/unmarshal?

With your current configuration you presumably have a `@XmlElement` annotation on a setter method where the data type is wrong, as a commenter mentioned. It's not clear from your question why you need setA take a String rather than boolean parameter, but if you can change the type to boolean on the setter then that also works.

EDIT:

Based on your comment below, it seems like you have two choices:

Write an `@XmlAdapter`, or

Make a setter/getter pair for a string field and an isA that is a calculate field (this is the way I've always done it because it just seems a bit more straightforward):

```
String a;

void setA(String);
String getA();

// calcualted field:
boolean isA() {
    // or whatever your real implementation is
    return a.equals("yes"); 
}
```

Comment: the setter has to be a string because in the xml files there a strings link "yes/no", "on/off", "in/out" and so on. I don't think jaxb is smart enough to automaticly convert that to boolean...

Comment: Aaaah... In that case, you need to delegate the conversion stuff to JAXB, not do it in your class. Just make a setter that accepts a `boolean`, then check out the stuff in [this package](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/package-summary.html) to find out about custom data type conversion.

Comment: More stuff to check out: http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2005/09/using_jaxb_20s.html. If you're confused regarding how to use this when making the annotations yourself, I can advise you to create some XML Schema, customize bindings using inline elements or a bindings file, then create classes from it with XJC and check the annotations in them. A good way to learn what's expected to be there.

Comment: +1 for `@XmlAccessType.FIELD` and `XmlAdapter`.  I have included a full example in my answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7876493/jax-b-is-interpreting-to-much-while-unmarshalling/7877499#7877499